# FlutterFlow- How to remove/delete item from datatype Map field?

Tags: dart

Having trouble removing items from a datatype (map) field. Do I need to write a custom function for this? How would I remove just one item from this field by using the contactUID and leave the others? I've googled and youtubed and found zero guidance. None of the attempts I've tried using FF functionality seem to work. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can delete using this function.

```
eventContacts.removeWhere((element) => element['contactUID'] == 'XXXX');
```

Comment: ty, Roger. Getting the error "The method 'removeWhere' isn't defined for the type 'BuiltList'." Unfortunately, this isn't pure dart. It's FlutterFlow's interpretation of dart.

Comment: You can convert this BuiltList into a List?